# angular1 & ionic1 update ui-ref after radiobutton selection

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a bit lost. I try to update the `ui-ref` of a button, after the user click on one of to radio buttons. The `ui-ref` gets updated correctly but the automaticly generated href stays the same. What are I am doing wrong?

Code in the view:

```
<div ng-controller="radiotCtrl">
    <div class="list" >
            <ion-radio ng-repeat="item in radiotList"
                     ng-value="item.value"
                     ng-model="data.radiot">
            {{ item.text }}
          </ion-radio>
        </div>
      <div  ui-sref='{{ data.radiot }}'>  <a  id="button14" class=" button button-positive  button-block button-outline ">Next</a></div>
   </div>
```

and the controller:

```
.controller('radiotCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.radiotList = [
        { text: "Selection 1", value: 'mynav.sele1' },
        { text: "Selection 2", value: 'mynav.sele2' },

    ];

    $scope.data = {
        radiot: 'mynav.sele1'
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ui-sref** does not support two way data binding. here is the discussion about this topic on github: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/395

a simple and working solution for me was to use ng-click instead:

Code in the view:

```
 <div ng-controller="RadioBuCtrl">
<form class="list ">
<ion-radio ng-model="user.answer" ng-value="'mynav.optionone'">Option 1</ion-radio>
<ion-radio ng-model="user.answer" ng-value="'mynav.optiontwo'">Option 2</ion-radio>
</form>
<a ng-click="submitAnswer(user)" class="button button-positive">Next</a>
</div>
```

and the controller:

```
.controller('RadioBuCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.submitAnswer=function(user){
 $state.go(user.answer);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place `ui-sref` on anchor(`a`) tag so that it will generate correct `href` by evaluating state provided to it.

```
<div>  
   <a ui-sref='{{ data.radiot }}' id="button14" 
     class=" button button-positive  button-block button-outline ">
       Next
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: still the same problem, the href gets generated from the `$scope.data = {
        radiot: 'mynav.sele1'
    };`placeholder

Comment: Could you create a problem plunkr?